# jquery autocomplete not working inside an ajax loaded form in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

in my rails application im loading a compose mail form by sending ajax request

the code of my compose.js file is

> $('#main').html("<%= j render :partial =>"smails/form" %>");

now in my compose form i have implemented an autocomplete field using jquery autocomplete plugin which is working fine when im loading the form without ajax. i think this is because im using **document.ready**, but i dont know how to use anything else.

code for my autocomlete.js.coffee file

```
$(document).ready ->
  split = (val) ->
    val.split /,\s*/
  extractLast = (term) ->
    split(term).pop()
  $('#smail_receiver').autocomplete
             source: "/autocomplete/users"
             search: ->
               term = extractLast(@value)
               false  if term.length < 2
             focus: ->
               false
             select: (event,ui) ->
               terms = split(@value)
               terms.pop()
               terms.push ui.item.value
               terms.push ""
               @value = terms.join(",")
               false
```

i also tried document.on

Comment: Please be more precise about what's going wrong. Are there any errors in the browser console? What happens if you put the line `console.log 'foo'` immediately before the `$('#smail_receiver').autocomplete` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way by using the "on" binding but you could just call your:

```
$('#smail_receiver').autocomplete
```

in the success method of the ajax call that creates the form.  You could also put it in your compose.js file after the form is rendered.

As said above there is probably a tidier solution but this would do the trick.

Comment: you mean adding that line in the compose.js
and removing document.ready from here?

Comment: Yes, remove the autocomplete line(s) from document.ready and ad them into the compose.js (after the form render).  That way you can be sure it is attached to the controls in the form that got rendered.  If it still isn't working, I would do some trial and error to see if anything is getting bound (ie. put an alert on a keyup event on that text field).  If that works, then maybe it's in your autocomplete code.